# Exception while uploading pdf file using Jersey Restful WS using Multipart/Multifeature

Tags: web-services, rest, file-upload, jersey

I have enabled MutiPartFeature in web.xml to upload pdf file using Jersey Restful API and included all the required jars. However I am getting below mentioned exception while running the code. Interestingly the missing method as mentioned in the exception is already there in guava-13.jar. Please help.

Error 500--Internal Server Error

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Sets.newIdentityHashSet()Ljava/util/Set;
at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.(CommonConfig.java:212)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$State.(ResourceConfig.java:107)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.(ResourceConfig.java:333)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:453)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.(WebComponent.java:302)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:240)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:299)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:250)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.initServletInstance(StubSecurityHelper.java:94)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:82)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:74)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.(StubLifecycleHelper.java:60)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.(StubLifecycleHelper.java:34)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.initStubLifecycleHelper(ServletStubImpl.java:638)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:579)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:295)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:235)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3284)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3254)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2163)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2089)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2074)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1512)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

Comment: looks like a classpath misconfiguration or missing lib, what build tool are you using? I suggest you to use a build tool with dependency management so you don't have to add jar manually and you delegate to the build tool this problem.

Comment: I am using ant to build the project. However I have verified that actual jar file is present in the deployed war file. Still I am getting the above mentioned exception.

Comment: dependencies are not always easy to get right, I strongly suggest - if you can - to use a build tool with dependency management. It *could* be that another different version of guava is inside another library and the class loader is picking up the wrong one that doesn't have that particular method.